# Matlab find x value for y max

Tags: matlab, graph

I have the data sets MI and XLead and create a graph like this: `plot(Xlead,MI)`

That graph has a peak - I can find the MI value at the peak like this: `maxMI = max(MI);`, but how do I find the Xlead value for when MI is max?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The max function returns an array of two objects:

```
[C,I] = max(...)
```

C - is the max value, I are the indices of the max value

So if you do:

```
[maxMi, ind] = max(MI);
maxX = Xlead(ind)
```

then you should get the value of X for the max MI in the maxX

Comment: no prob :-) it's just that I'm in a race with my buddy. whoever gets 300 first wins a beer :D thanks for your help! Appreciate it much :D